# Scrapy stucks again and again while running

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

The question is solved. The answer is in this [tutorial](https://coderslegacy.com/python/concurrent-requests-in-scrapy/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20Scrapy,server%20at%20the%20same%20time.).

I have been running a scrapy script for crawling and scraping. It was all doing fine. But while running, it keeps getting stuck at some point.
Here is what it shows

```
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1795 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 1716 items (at 0 items/min)
```

I then stopped the code running with Contorl+Z and reran the spider. And then again, after crawling and scraping some data, it gets stuck. Did you face that problem before? How did you overcome it?

Here is the [link](https://github.com/pranto667/doctorgrades-scrapy-playwright-massage_therapy.git) to the whole code

Here is the code of the spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from healthgrades.items import HealthgradesItem
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod 

# make the header elements like they are in a dictionary
def get_headers(s, sep=': ', strip_cookie=True, strip_cl=True, strip_headers: list = []) -> dict():
d = dict()
for kv in s.split('\n'):
    kv = kv.strip()
    if kv and sep in kv:
        v=''
        k = kv.split(sep)[0]
        if len(kv.split(sep)) == 1:
            v = ''
        else:
            v = kv.split(sep)[1]
        if v == '\'\'':
            v =''
        # v = kv.split(sep)[1]
        if strip_cookie and k.lower() == 'cookie': continue
        if strip_cl and k.lower() == 'content-length': continue
        if k in strip_headers: continue
        d[k] = v
return d

# spider class
    class DoctorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'doctor'
    allowed_domains = ['healthgrades.com']
    url = 'https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Massage%20Therapy&entityCode=PS444&where=New%20York&pageNu    m={}&sort.provider=bestmatch&='

# change the header of bot to look like a browser
    def start_requests(self):
        h = get_headers(
            '''
            accept: */*
            accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, be
            accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
            dnt: 1
            origin: https://www.healthgrades.com
            referer: https://www.healthgrades.com/
            sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
            sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
            sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
            sec-fetch-dest: empty
            sec-fetch-mode: cors
        vsec-fetch-site: cross-site
            user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
            '''
        )

        for i in range(1, 6): # Change the range to the page numbers. more improvement can be done
            # GET request. url to first page
            yield scrapy.Request(self.url.format(i), headers =h, meta=dict(
                playwright = True,
                playwright_include_page = True,
                playwright_page_methods =    [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'h3.card-name a')] # for     waiting for a particular element to load 
            )) 

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div h3.card-name a::attr(href)'): # individual doctor's link
            yield response.follow(link.get(), callback = self.parse_categories) # enter into the website
        
    def parse_categories(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item  = HealthgradesItem(), selector = response)

        l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1')
        l.add_xpath('specialty', '//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p/span[1]')
        l.add_xpath('practice_name', '//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/p')
        l.add_xpath('address', 'string(//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/address)')

        yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: That line just shows you statistics.  The most common reasons for hanging are because one of your requests is timing out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, there is a limit to concurrent settings.

[Here is the solution](https://coderslegacy.com/python/concurrent-requests-in-scrapy/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20Scrapy,server%20at%20the%20same%20time.)

> ### Concurrent Requests
>
> Adding concurrency into Scrapy is actually a very simple task. There is already a setting for the number of concurrent requests allowed, which you just have to modify.
>
> You can choose to modify this in the custom settings of the spider you’ve made, or the global settings which effect all spiders.
>
> **Global**
>
> To add this globally, just add the following line to your settings file.
>
> ```
> CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 30
> ```
>
> We’ve set the number of concurrent requests to 30. You may use any value that you wish, within a reasonable limit though.
>
> **Local**
>
> To add settings locally, we have to use custom settings to add concurrency requests to our Scrapy spider.
>
> ```
> custom_settings = {
>      'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' = 30
> }
> ```
>
> **Additional Settings**
>
> There are many additional settings that you can use instead of, or together with CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.
>
> - `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` – Sets the number of concurrent requests per IP address.
> - `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` – Defines the number of concurrent requests allowed for each domain.
> - `MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` – Sets a maximum limit on the number of concurrent requests allowed for a domain.